# Generate dynamic surveys using Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a web app using Flask to offer surveys to users. The number of questions on the survey and the type of questions isn't known until runtime. I finally have the code working properly, and would like some feedback on how pythonic the code is and what I can do to improve it.

To account for a single form page that can display multiple types of questions, I have the following in my `forms.py` file (I'm going with the PEP 8 notation that lines 99 characters long is acceptable for teams that prefer it):

```
class FieldsRequiredForm(FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        def render_field(self, field, render_kw):
            render_kw.setdefault('required', True)
            return super().render_field(field, render_kw)
```

Here is the route code:

```
@bp.route('/survey/<string:slug>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def survey(slug):
    class SurveyForm(FieldsRequiredForm):
        pass

    survey = Survey.query.filter_by(slug=slug).first_or_404()
    questions = survey.questions
    question_ids = [question.id for question in questions]
    if 'answers' not in session:
        session['answers'] = json.dumps({id: None for id in question_ids})
        form = F()
    answers = json.loads(session['answers'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        record_submitted_answer()
        answers = json.loads(session['answers'])
    if None in answers.values():
        question = get_next_question()
        SurveyForm.question_id = HiddenField(default=question.id)
        if question.category == 'word':
            SurveyForm.answer = StringField(question.question)
        elif question.category == 'likert':
            SurveyForm.answer = RadioField(question.question, choices=tuple(likert().items()))
        SurveyForm.submit = SubmitField('Submit')
    else:
        SurveyForm.answer = StringField()
    form = F()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if None not in answers.values():
            write_answers_to_database(survey=survey)
            if survey.ty:
                lines = iter(survey.ty.splitlines())
            else:
                with open('app/static/ty.txt', 'r') as f:
                    lines = f.readlines()
            ty = [line.strip() for line in lines]
            return render_template('ty.html', ty=ty)
        return redirect(url_for('survey.survey', slug=slug))
    return render_template('survey.html', form=form)
```

Please, tell me what I did wrong or could have done better.